# How to update the configmap data using parameters in openshift?

Tags: yaml, openshift-origin, openshift-3, okd

I have the following openshift template:

```
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: test-python
  annotations:
    tags: python,django
    iconClass: icon-python

objects:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: war-config

    data:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: qwerty
      POSTGRES_USER: warrior
      warrior_conf.conf: |
        [WARRIOR]
        API_URL=${api_url}
        MGMT_SVC_1=ne-mgmt-svc
        MGMT_SVC_2=manager-svc

.
.
.
.
<other -resources>
.
.
.



parameters:
  - name: "api_url"
    description: Enter the api_url
    value: test.svc
    required: true
```

Here im passing `api_url`, as a parameter, but issue here after deploying the template, the parameter in the config map is not getting replaced with desired value i.e: `test.svc` instead it remains as `API_URL=${api_url}`

Please suggest me if i have to follow some other syntax to update this using parameters.